# Popen.communicate() returns only err when running ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to run ffmpeg from python and get some reasonable output. Doesn't matter what ffmpeg's log level is set, the only output I get from Popen.communicate() is err one. The content isn't an error however. I tried the same code to run other commands (ls) and it seems to be Ok with both out and err outputs.

I checked here and Google and unfortunately found nothing. Most of the examples use os or commands modules, not subprocess.

This is my test code:

```
command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-v', 'debug',
        '-i', '1.mov',
        '-vcodec', 'libx264',
        '-profile:v', 'high',
        '-preset', 'slower',
        '-b:v', '1000k',
        '-vf', 'scale=-1:720',
        '-threads', '0', 
        '-acodec', 'libfdk_aac',
        '-b:a', '192k',
        '-y',   
        '2.mp4',
        ]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err =  p.communicate()
f = open('out.log', 'w')
f.write(out)
f.close()
f = open('error.log', 'w')
f.write(err)
f.close()
```

Have you ever see something like this? Am I doing any mistakes or is there an bug in ffmpeg?

Comment: Try running the exact same command arguments in a terminal, see what happens. To get the actual arguments as a string, you can replace `ffmpeg` with `echo` in your python script if you're on Linux.

Comment: Running the command in terminal is OK. I does what I want it to do and console output isn't an error. Therefore I expect the same output in out return value of communicate(). And it's in err part. I tried to run with other command also and there it was OK.

Answer (score 3):

I seemed to misinterpreted stdout and stderr in case of ffmpeg. All the "console output" is normally directed to stderr. Redirecting stderr to stdout shall solve the issue. This is how:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Sorry for this ... I was too concentrated to Python part that I completely overlooked quite obvious thing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

By default `ffmpeg` logs to stderr i.e., you see the expected behavior.

To save the stderr output of a command to a file, you don't need `.communicate()`:

```
import subprocess 

with open("stderr.log", "wb") as logfile:
    subprocess.check_call(command, stderr=logfile)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about check_call. I don't save the output to file, but process the data somehow. It was just easier here to put something shorter and not spam with a lot of other code :-)